# Sign out clients only in IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

Is there a way to execute a single-sign-out **for clients only** using IdentityServer4? I have no problem executing single-sign-out for clients and IdentityServer using the `endsession` endpoint. What I would like to do, however, is provide a way to force all clients to re-authenticate upon next request (to get fresh claims) but not force the user to re-enter credentials.

The use case is for the user to edit profile information which is stored in claims. For example, their name. When the user submits a change to this information, all other clients need to be made aware that the claims they currently have are no longer valid. This can be achieved by signing the user out completely, but then the user must re-enter their id and password.

Looking at the flow, I guess what I'm trying to do is execute the internal `EndSessionCallbackEndpoint` directly, without removing the authentication cookie for IdentityServer itself.

Comment: if you look into quickstarts, idsrv host is just an asp.net app, and logout for it should be called explicitly. you can skip that step, but continue to logged out view. theoretically should work.

Comment: Thanks, @d_f, that's kind of what I ended up doing (see below), but it just "smells" wrong to me. Seems like there should be a way of expressing this indent in the call to the `endsession` endpoint, and not by detecting magic URLs.

Comment: instead of "magic url" which really "smells" as it uses an entity for the purpose it was not aimed for, I'd add a special "magic" parameter. almost the same, but smells much less, imho

Comment: I guess that's my question, though: how do I get that parameter to the Logout method? As far as I can tell, the `endsession` endpoint only forwards a logout id to the `GET Logout` method.

Comment: well, currently `EndSessionRequestValidator` unlike for instance `TokenRequestValidator` does not have any extensibility points, as well as `ValidatedEndSessionRequest`, so the only alternative without rewriting everything is to employ the `state` param. according to the spec it does not suppose any validation and should be kept and sent back to the client as it is. not sure if the smell would be much better, but maybe a bit : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a solution that is working, but this really feels like I'm abusing the system. If anyone has a "standard" way to provide the expected functionality, please let me know.

This solution alters the `Logout` method to "sniff" for a magic `PostLogoutRedirectUri` and to skip the deletion of the local authentication cookie. Obviously not particularly scalable or elegant.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(LogoutInputModel model)
{
    // build a model so the logged out page knows what to display
    var vm = await BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync(model.LogoutId);

    // Special post-logout URL that should only log out clients, but keep the local authentication cookie.
    bool clientsOnly = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.PostLogoutRedirectUri) && vm.PostLogoutRedirectUri.StartsWith("https://example.com/EditProfile");

    if (User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true && !clientsOnly)
    {
        // delete local authentication cookie
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();

        // raise the logout event
        await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLogoutSuccessEvent(User.GetSubjectId(), User.GetDisplayName()));
    }

    // check if we need to trigger sign-out at an upstream identity provider
    if (vm.TriggerExternalSignout)
    {
        // build a return URL so the upstream provider will redirect back to us after the
        // user has logged out. this allows us to then complete our single sign-out processing.
        string url = Url.Action("Logout", new { logoutId = vm.LogoutId });

        // this triggers a redirect to the external provider for sign-out
        return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = url }, vm.ExternalAuthenticationScheme);
    }

    return View("LoggedOut", vm);
}
```

Comment: Please note that `PostLogoutRedirectUri` is null in case the client doesn't provide an id_token.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly straightforward and exposed via public APIs (`IIdentityServerInteractionService`) in IDS4. This is a really simplified example of the steps. This covers both from and back channel signout as both are triggered by the request to the `SignOutIFrameUrl`.

First we need to create a signout context and redirect to an action that will perform the signout:

```
var signoutId = await _identityInteractionService.CreateLogoutContextAsync();
return RedirectToAction(nameof(ClientSignout), new { signoutId });
```

ClientSignout action:

```
var context = await _identityInteractionService.GetLogoutContextAsync(signoutId);
ViewBag.SignOutIframeUrl = context.SignOutIFrameUrl;
return View();
```

ClientSignout.cshtml:

```
<iframe src="@ViewBag.SignOutIframeUrl" id="SignOutIframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="display:none" />
//TODO: Detect client-side once iframe has loaded and then maybe redirect somewhere else?
```

The code here does not touch the current authentication session at all but an alternative would be to force a refresh of the current session ID and thus trigger a refresh in any clients with session monitoring in place.

ETA: the more I think about it I think the client side session monitoring approach is the right one. The client has control over what to do next then. Another option is the client doing periodic calls to the userinfo endpoint to get updated claims using the provided access token. We actually use all 3 mechanisms to good effect.

October 2020:
Further to this - I think these day's I'd favour using the OIDC back channel spec instead: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-backchannel-1_0.html

I've done a PoC recently whereby backend code can end client sessions for a given set of users and clients without involving a user's browser at all. Powerful if you want to force reauthentication due to policy changes or a "sign me out everywhere" feature in the IDP.

Note however that the standard `identityserver4` code needs tweaking to make this work as it's currently assumed it will only be used as part of the normal signout flow.

Comment: this is just copy-paste from the original qickstarts. the OP performed the same more elegant without copying&pasting. his solution might be called "perfect" when `EndSessionRequestValidator` had an extensibility point like the others request validators.

Comment: @d_f I'm not sure what point you're trying to make. Does this not address the original question of how to explicitly sign out clients only? If OP wants to build this into the flow of saving a form then the above can easily be adapted to work with that without the user even being aware. I still think the session monitoring spec is a more suitable way of handling this though. If you do a SignInAsync and pass an AuthenticationProperties object with `session_id` removed then IDS4 will automatically generate a new one and notify all clients to refresh.

Comment: I agree, the session monitoring approach would work well. but that a little bit changes the whole concept. and if we keep the original concept, the OP's solution is solid and simple.

Comment: I agree it will work but the code sample shown only shows how to not sign out locally and not now client sign outs are actually performed. i.e. the magic is happening in the "LoggedOut" view.